# inplace сортировка

Tags: c++, сортировка, память

Пытаюсь реализовать inplace сортировку кучей, но получаю ошибочный результат

v - индекс вершины родителя, 2v - левый ребенок, 2v + 1 - правый ребенок

1. ExtractMax() - (extractMax меняет корень и последний элемент, потом запускает SiftDown). SiftDown меняет нарушение кучи и опускает большие элементы вниз (в общем случае для кучи с минимумом в корне).
2. Heapify() - хотим хранить кучу с максимумом в корне, поэтому все числа массива умножим на -1, чтобы процедура SiftDown не менялась (работаем с обычной кучей на минимум, потом в конце умножаем на -1, чтобы вернуть исходный массив)

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
//устраняет нарушения в куче с минимумом в корне, опускает бОльшие элементы вниз
void SiftDown(std::vector<int>& mas, int v) {
    int size = mas.size();
    while (2 * v <= size) {
        int u = 2 * v;
        if ((u + 1 <= size) && (mas[u] > mas[u + 1])) {
            u ++;
        }
        if (mas[v] <= mas[u]) { break; }
        std::swap(mas[u], mas[v]);
        v = u;
    }
}

//умножаем все элементы массива на -1, чтобы пользоваться SiftDown и не менять его под максимум в корне
void MultiplicateByOne(std::vector<int>& mas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.size(); ++i) {
        mas[i] *= (-1);
    }
}

// меняет местами элемент в корне и на последнем месте, далее запускает SiftDown от корневого элемента
void ExtractMax(std::vector<int>& mas) {
    int size = mas.size();
    std::swap(mas[0], mas[size - 1]);
    SiftDown(mas, 0);
}

// по введённому массиву строим корректную кучу
void Heapify(std::vector<int>& mas) {
    for (int i = mas.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        SiftDown(mas, i);
    }
}


void InplaceHeapSort(std::vector<int>& mas) {
    // умножили все элементы на -1, чтобы работал SiftDown с минимумом в корне
    MultiplicateByOne(mas);
    // строим корректную кучу с минимумом в корне
    Heapify(mas); 
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.size(); ++i) {
        ExtractMax(mas);
    }
    // возвращаем элементы к исходному виду
    MultiplicateByOne(mas);
}

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> mas(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int item;
        std::cin >> item;
        mas[i] = item;
    }
    InplaceHeapSort(mas);

    for (int item : mas) {
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1459722/edit) метку языка программирования.

Comment: Корень - нулевой элемент (`v=0`). Его левый сын `2v = 2 * 0 = 0`. Что-то не так.

Comment: `ExtractMax` должен уменьшать размер кучи на единицу.

Comment: Умножать элементы на -1 не надо. Куча максимальная. Максимальный элемент из корня кучи переносится в конец массива, куча сокращается на единицу, корень кучи просеивается вниз. Процесс повторяется пока куча не опустеет.